# Passing through value to dashboard prompt obiee 12c

Tags: obiee

I navigate between different dashboard pages via action links.
I have on top of all the pages a dashboard prompt which contains a division as a dimension to filter on. This division has different roles so I have 3 aliases for it. However I don't want the end consumer to bother with these different roles, that's why I pass through the value of the division via a presentation variable.

But sometimes the value doesn't appear in the prompt but the analysis beneath it filters on the correct value (so the passing through seems to work okay. And sometimes it does work correctly.

I can't seem to figure out the difference from when it works and when it doesn't. I have the scope of all my dashboardprompts on 'dashboard' and actions from 'navigate to bi content' is also on 'dashboard'.

I don't pass through the value of the dimension via the presentation variable but I am using the 'is prompted' option. So this looks like the value is indeed in my prompt but just doesn't show up.

Has anyone else have had this problem and can help me solve this?

Thanks!